# Indexing the "last added" row of a set of strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a database with 1Mil+ rows in it.
This database consists (for the sake of this question) of 2 columns; user_id, and username.
These values are not controlled by my application; I am not always certain that these are the current correct values. All I know is that the user_id is guaranteed to be unique. I get periodic updates which allow me to update my database to ensure I have an "eventually consistent" version of the user_id/username mapping.

I would like to be able to retrieve the latest addition of a certain username; "older" results should be ignored.

I believe there are two possible approaches here:
 - indexing: there should be an index of `username:row` (hashmap?) where `username` is always the last added username; so gets updated on each row addition, or update.
 - Setting username as unique, and doing an `on conflict update` to set the old row to the empty string, and the new row to the username

From what I've understood about indexing, it sounds like its the faster option (and wont require me checking the unicity of 1Mil rows in my database). I also hear hashmaps are a pain because they require rebuilding, so feel free to give other ideas.

My current implementation does a full search over the entire database, which is beginning to get quite slow at 1Mil+ rows. It currently gets the "last" value of this added string; which I am not even sure is a valid assumption at this point.

Given a sample database:

```
user_id, username
3      , bob
2      , alice
4      , joe
1      , bob
```

I would expect a search of `username = bob` to return (1, bob).
I cannot rely on ID ordering to solve this, since there is no linearity to which ID is assigned to which username.

Comment: . . Tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no way to get insertion order unless you provide a column with this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using:

```
select distinct on (id) s.*
from sample s
where s.username = 'bob'
order by s.id desc;
```

For performance, you want an index on `sample(username, id)`.

Alternatively, if you are doing periodic bulk updates, then you can construct a version of the table with unique rows per *username*:

```
create table most_recent_sample as
    select max(id) as id, username
    from sample
    group by username;

create index idx_most_recent_sample_username on most_recent_sample(username);
```

This might take a short amount of time, but you are doing the update anyway.

Comment: The ID's arent necessarily ordered; I can't rely on the ID size to determine latest username, so i dont think either of these solutions would work. (sorry for wrong missing info, added to post)